# Cannot put margin between React Router Navlink

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple navbar using React Bootstrap:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import './NavbarDefault.css';

const DefaultNavbar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Demo</Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav className="mer-auto">
          <NavLink
              className="nav-link-custom"
              activeClassName="nav-link-custom-active"
              to="/login"
            >
              Login
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            className="nav-link-custom"
            activeClassName="nav-link-custom-active"
            to="/register"
          >
            Sign up
          </NavLink>
        </Nav>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  )
};

export default DefaultNavbar;
```

The navbar works fine however there isn't any padding between the links "Login" and "Sign up". I have tried adding the Bootstrap css class `mr-3` to `NavLink` but this didn't make a difference. I also tried wrapping both `NavLink`'s in `div` and putting the `mr-3` class there, but that also didn't work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If they're just `<NavLinks>` they're outputting `<a>` & these are just inline elements. Give them a CSS property of `display: inline-block;` to allow the padding and/or margin

Comment: I tired that. I also tried `display: block;` and neither worked. Do they have to be wrapped in a specific type of container?